# VBA code to save and update worksheet only works for me?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a worksheet which should be saved and the Excel User's name be updated in cell P1 and the current time stamped in Q1. This should also lock cells for editing with a password when the save button is pressed.

However, it works fine when I update the sheet but not so with other users. They have macros enabled so I know that isn't the cause.

Below is the code that I am using:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Range("P1") = "Last Update: " & Format(Now)
Range("Q1").Value = Application.UserName 'Stamp the current user name
Worksheets("Org Chart").Activate
ActiveSheet.Protect ("Password")
End Sub
```

Is there something wrong in this code that could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, this question. I apologize, the user said that they were "sure" they enabled macros but apparently they had not.

However, I do think the alternative to using the environment name as opposed to the program license name is better so I appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
Range("Q1").Value = Environ("username")
```

this should gives different value when different user open the workbook.  If multiple users using the same workstation to open the workbook, you will need some other technology...

Comment: Everyone is at a different workstation but that doesn't seem to be working either.